"Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64" error when using ncurses getch() method in C++
I am trying to write a program using the ncurses library, specifically using the getch() method. However the instant I use it I get a symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 error
This is a dummy program I wrote to demonstrate:
test.cpp :
#include <iostream>
#include <curses.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
        int random;
        random = getch();
        cout << random;
        return 0;
}

Compilation command :
clang++ test.cpp -o test
Error:
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_stdscr", referenced from:
      _main in test-430e5f.o
  "_wgetch$NCURSES60", referenced from:
      _main in test-430e5f.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

and when I use the -v option I get :
Apple clang version 16.0.0 (clang-1600.0.26.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin24.0.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
 "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx15.0.0 -Wundef-prefix=TARGET_OS_ -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -emit-obj -mrelax-all -dumpdir test- -disable-free -clear-ast-before-backend -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name test.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mframe-pointer=all -fno-strict-return -ffp-contract=on -fno-rounding-math -funwind-tables=2 -target-sdk-version=15.1 -fvisibility-inlines-hidden-static-local-var -fno-modulemap-allow-subdirectory-search -target-cpu penryn -tune-cpu generic -debugger-tuning=lldb -target-linker-version 1115.7.3 -v -fcoverage-compilation-dir=/Users/parsafarjam/IntroInfo/Projet-Info111-2048 -resource-dir /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/16 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include -internal-isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1 -internal-isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/local/include -internal-isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/16/include -internal-externc-isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -internal-externc-isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include -Wno-reorder-init-list -Wno-implicit-int-float-conversion -Wno-c99-designator -Wno-final-dtor-non-final-class -Wno-extra-semi-stmt -Wno-misleading-indentation -Wno-quoted-include-in-framework-header -Wno-implicit-fallthrough -Wno-enum-enum-conversion -Wno-enum-float-conversion -Wno-elaborated-enum-base -Wno-reserved-identifier -Wno-gnu-folding-constant -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir=/Users/parsafarjam/IntroInfo/Projet-Info111-2048 -ferror-limit 19 -stack-protector 1 -fstack-check -mdarwin-stkchk-strong-link -fblocks -fencode-extended-block-signature -fregister-global-dtors-with-atexit -fgnuc-version=4.2.1 -fno-cxx-modules -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fmax-type-align=16 -fcommon -fcolor-diagnostics -clang-vendor-feature=+disableNonDependentMemberExprInCurrentInstantiation -fno-odr-hash-protocols -clang-vendor-feature=+enableAggressiveVLAFolding -clang-vendor-feature=+revert09abecef7bbf -clang-vendor-feature=+thisNoAlignAttr -clang-vendor-feature=+thisNoNullAttr -clang-vendor-feature=+disableAtImportPrivateFrameworkInImplementationError -D__GCC_HAVE_DWARF2_CFI_ASM=1 -o /var/folders/mc/1nj08rkj6qv3zg6g1vqc5__h0000gn/T/test-4b0b5e.o -x c++ test.cpp
clang -cc1 version 16.0.0 (clang-1600.0.26.4) default target x86_64-apple-darwin24.0.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/Library/Frameworks"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/16/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include
 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
 "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -lto_library /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/libLTO.dylib -no_deduplicate -dynamic -arch x86_64 -platform_version macos 15.0.0 15.1 -syslibroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -mllvm -enable-linkonceodr-outlining -o test -L/usr/local/lib /var/folders/mc/1nj08rkj6qv3zg6g1vqc5__h0000gn/T/test-4b0b5e.o -lc++ -lSystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/lib/clang/16/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_stdscr", referenced from:
      _main in test-4b0b5e.o
  "_wgetch$NCURSES60", referenced from:
      _main in test-4b0b5e.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have tried brew reinstall ncurses and no luck. I've also tried g++ and I get the same error. I've tried forcing it to use C++20 with --std=c++20 and that does not help either.
I'm running this on an Intel Mac, using MacOS Sequoia 15.0.1.
Any helo would be appreciated

You're not linking the ncurses library. Just because clang finds the header, doesn't mean it automatically links the .a / .so

Compilation and linking are (conceptually) two different steps. When compiling you use the header file, but when linking you do not use the library. You have to tell the compiler/linker to link with the ncurses library. At minimum this means adding -lncurses to your compilation command.
